# How can I put value of input in localStorage

Tags: java, jquery

im trying to add input text to local storage

```js
document.getElementById('nick').value;localStorage.setItem('nick', value);
```

Comment: ...and what's the question?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('nick', document.getElementById('nick').value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to implement:

```
var val = document.getElementById('nick').value;
localStorage.setItem('nick', val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage.setItem` for this

```
// To set the value:
localStorage.setItem('localStorageNick', document.getElementById('nick').value);

// To get the value:
localStorage.getItem('localStorageNick')
```

Comment: thnx u help me a lot

Comment: Your very welcome, if you found this question helpfull please feel free to upvote the answer. If this answer solved your problem please mark it as answered.